# Android Performance

Tags: java, android, performance

My android application growing and getting more interactive.
Now I'm wondering are there methods to make the Code more efficient except this

[Android Performance tips](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/articles/perf-tips.html) 
How I can measure method call efficiency?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to start with traceview in order to get an overview of where your hotspots are (if any). The rule of optimization is that you should focus only where there is a significant bottleneck.

The android developer docs have a nice introduction titled [Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) online.

This will show you all your method calls and what percentage of time each took, how many times each was called, etc. Be sure to focus only on methods in your app or directly called by your app -- since all method calls will be recorded, there will be many you have no control over.

See also: [Understanding Traceview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758071/understanding-traceview)